# $\sigma$-structure $\mathbb{1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, terminology, universal-algebra

$\exists \mathbb{1}.\forall \left(A,\left(R^{\mathcal A}\right)_{R\in \sigma}\right). \exists f:\mathcal A \rightarrow_{hom} \mathbb{1}.$

Or in Words: Let $\sigma$ be a signature.

> Show that a $\sigma$-structure $\mathbb{1}$ exists so that for any $\sigma$-structure $\mathcal A$ exists a (unique) homomorphism from $\mathcal A$ to $\mathbb 1$. This 1-structure is supposed to be unique upto isomorphism.

The tutorial in class concluded with $\mathbb 1 = (\{1\},(\{1\}^k)_{R\in\sigma.k=\operatorname{arity}(R)})$ (edit: not exactly like that, but all symbols of $\sigma$ interpreted in $\mathcal 1$ would have to be there ...). However, I had thought that would be too simple, if an order relation, eg. $>$ was concerned, $1>1$ shouldn't be in $\sigma$, although that's my own notion as the script is quite sparse. There, a signature just contains ''symbols'', which is my problem, I guess, as all given definitions seem to be met.

I imagine instead a homomorphism to map substructures to a universal structure, that contains all admissible objects and relations (or functions etc.): $\exists U_1. \forall x. x \in U_1$ together with all possible relations over that set.

Now, there doesn't seem to exist a bijection between the two solutions, so only one can be correct. I assume that I am wrong. But *how*?

We didn't chose any fundamental set theory, so I suppose the setup wasn't rigid enough and I ran into some kind of Russel's paradox. Books on abstract algebra are somewhat intimidating so I'd appreciate a quick heads up.

Now the actual question, if you will, is this homomorphism called a universal property? Or perhaps an initial object?

Comment: There is no problem with $1<1$: as you note, these are only *relation symbols* in this context, i.e. no further axioms are posed on them.

Comment: I don't get it, what is the reason to choose a specific symbol if different ''interpretations'' don't have any connection? Isn't this trivial and most likely not what a mathematician would be interested in?

Comment: @vectorious There's two questions there: why would one use the specific symbol "$<$" to refer to something that's not even a preorder, and why would mathematicians care about arbitrary structures in general? For the first one, the point is that it's often useful to consider a specific class of structures in a broader context. E.g. every linear order can be thought of as a directed graph, where there's an arrow from $a$ to $b$ if $a<b$. In this context, for simplicity we keep using the same symbol, to avoid the tedium of frequently introducing new symbols which behave just as old ones. (cont'd)

Comment: For the second question, well, very strange-looking structures can turn out to be surprisingly interesting! For instance, consider the language consisting of three binary function symbols $+, -, f$ and a constant symbol $0$. The class of structures satisfying the law $$f(a_2, a_3)-f(a_1+a_2, a_3)+f(a_1, a_2+a_3)-f(a_1, a_2)=0$$ may seem really artificial; however, this law turns out to be very important - it's the **1-cocycle condition** in group cohomology! Of course working in maximum generality isn't always interesting, but at the same time it's often something we want to do.

Comment: The final question then is: which is the terminal object of the catealgebraic structures, specifically, what is it's signature - Does the question make sense? Then I should post it as a full question.

Comment: @vectorious It's not clear what the category of *all* algebraic structures is - what is a homomorphism between two structures in different signatures? This gets especially hairy when you think about composition: let's say we have two disjoint languages $\Sigma,\Pi$, two $\Sigma$-structures $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, a $\Pi$-structure $\mathcal{C}$, and morphisms $f: \mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ and $g:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$. Then $g\circ f$ needs to be a homomorphism of $\Sigma$-structures (cont'd)

Comment: - but what guarantees this, given that all the $\Sigma$-structure is forgotten at $\mathcal{C}$? If we avoid this by not allowing *any* morphisms between structures in different signatures, then we don't have a terminal object. If you really want something broader than the category of $\Sigma$-structures for a given $\Sigma$, the right thing to do in my opinion is look at the category of *pairs* $(\mathcal{A},\Sigma)$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\Sigma$-structure; there's a natural notion of morphism here (hint: send symbols to symbols of the same type), (cont'd)

Comment: and the terminal object in this category is the one-element structure in the language consisting of exactly one symbol of each type.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Homomorphisms from fields to rings exist, for example, or so I read. I was thinking that any language would have to include at least the identity operator or inequality, but that might seem to trivial and I see it rather defined in the meta language. This was a fruitful question. Thank you all.

Comment: @vectorious Any language **does** include $=$ and $\not=$, since $=$ (in modern logic at least) is taken as a logical symbol; that's not the issue here. How would you e.g. define a homomorphism from a linear order (with no functional structure) to a ring (with no relational structure)? In the case of fields and rings, since every field is the definable expansion of a unique ring we can conflate the field with its underlying ring, and then we're just looking at homomorphisms between rings, and little information is lost. But in general this doesn't work, and having "$=$" doesn't help.

Comment: Just to clarify: I meant signature but wrote language because I thought that was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear that $\mathbb{1}$ has the desired properties - as you note, although there are relation symbols that we're used to having negative properties (like $<$, which "should" be irreflexive), in this context symbols are "contextless" - all a binary relation symbol like "$<$" denotes is, well, a binary relation, and could indeed be reflexive.

So the real question is, why is $\mathbb{1}$ the unique (up to isomorphism) solution?

The first problem is that the structure you've outlined isn't technically a structure - it has a proper class of elements. More importantly for your intuition, though, it's **too** universal! Remember the goal is

> for any $\sigma$-structure $\mathcal{A}$ there exists a unique homomorphism from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathbb{1}$.

The key word there is "unique." If your structure is "too big," then there will be "too many" homomorphisms into it! For instance, take $\sigma$ to be the language of graphs (a single binary relation symbol) and consider as your universal structure [the countable random graph](http://modeltheory.wikia.com/wiki/Random_graph). This structure is "universal" in many senses - in particular, any countable graph admits a homomorphism into it. However, any countable graph admits *lots of* homomorphisms into it, so it has the wrong property! In category-theoretic language, we're looking for a *terminal object* in the category of $\sigma$-structures, and this terminal object can't be too "large" for the same reason that the terminal object in **Set** can't have more than one element.

---

If we drop the uniqueness requirement, then there are indeed lots of solutions - indeed, if $\mathcal{U}$ is any structure such that there is a homomorphism $h: \mathbb{1}\rightarrow\mathcal{U}$, then for any other structure $\mathcal{A}$ there is a homomorphism $f: \mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{U}$, given by $f=h\circ !$, where $!$ is the unique homomorphism from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathbb{1}$.

On the other hand, the requirement "there is a homomorphism $h: \mathbb{1}\rightarrow\mathcal{U}$" is not trivial: for example, if $\sigma$ consists of a single function symbol $f$, $\mathbb{1}$ is the one-element $\sigma$-structure, and $\mathcal{U}$ is the two-element $\sigma$-structure with elements $a, b$ and $f^\mathcal{U}(a)=b$ and $f^\mathcal{U}(b)=a$, then there is no homomorphism from $\mathbb{1}$ to $\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: The end confused me. I read that as $\not \exists \mathcal 1 \rightarrow A \Rightarrow \not \exists h$, but It doesn't seem implied. Is id not a homomorphism mapping 1 to U?

Comment: @vectorious "Is id not a homomorphism mapping 1 to U?" What? I don't understand what you're asking - id only *potentially* makes sense as a homomorphism from one structure to another if the former's domain is a subset of the latter, and I haven't specified what the domain of $\mathbb{1}$ is, so the identity map doesn't even need to be a *function* from $\mathbb{1}$ to $\mathcal{A}$! But suppose $\mathbb{1}$ has domain $\{a\}$, so id is in fact a function. Then in $\mathbb{1}$ we have $f(a)=a$, but in $\mathcal{A}$ we *don't* have $f(id(a))=id(a)$, so id isn't a homomorphism.

Comment: There are three points to this answer. (1) Whenever $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-structure, there is a unique homomorphism from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathbb{1}_\sigma$; and $\mathbb{1}_\sigma$ is the unique $\sigma$-structure with this property. (2) If we drop the uniqueness requirement, then there are lots of other examples - whenever $\mathcal{U}$ is a $\sigma$-structure such that there is a homomorphism $h:\mathbb{1}_\sigma\rightarrow\mathcal{U}$, then we have: "For every $\sigma$-structure $\mathcal{A}$, there is *at least one* homomorphism $\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{U}$. (cont'd)

Comment: (3) The condition in (2) isn't trivial - we can find an example of a structure $\mathcal{V}$ such that there **is no** homomorphism from $\mathbb{1}_\sigma$ to $\mathcal{V}$. Does that make sense?

Comment: @vectorious I've changed the variable name in the last paragraph - does this make things clearer?

Comment: Well, after your change my comment doesn't make sense, because I intended U as a universal set. I conclude the onus is on me to show U. Taking the differentiated naming from your comment, i don't see  $\not \exists h_V:\mathcal 1 \rightarrow V \Rightarrow \not \exists h_U: \mathcal 1 \rightarrow \mathcal U$; mostly because U is not trivial, if at all possible to define as a set. I found that a class of all sets was theorized, that satisfied my curiosity so far.